# Como juntar esses dois selects de uma mesma tabela no SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

Seguinte, preciso da quantidade por mês de cada cliente que entrou no ano consegui fazer isso, porém eu quero q seja mostrado em apenas 1 resultado. Como faço para juntar os dois SELECTS? Em ordem que seja adicionado ao lado direito do primeiro resultado "Entrada Mês\Ano" os Campos "QTD" e "Saída Mês Ano". Vejam a imagem q enviei.

Agradeço desde já!

OBS: Ambos fazem parte da mesma tabela só estão em colunas diferentes.

OBS: Tentei usar UNION porém UNION ele apenas agrupa os resultados em 2 campos e exclui o campo "Saída" tentei fazer uma subquery(sem sucesso).

[image: Resultado das SELECTS]

Comment: Provavelmente não entendi direito sua explicação do objetivo de sua query mas talvez um FULL OUTER JOIN destas duas subqueries sobre o campo mês/ano possa fornecer o resultado desejado.

Comment: Coloca o código pra criar sua tabela pra tentarmos reproduzir aqui. Não precisa de todos os dados, só uma parte... E coloca os seus SELECT em forma de texto também, não de imagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia Fernando!

Pensei aqui em duas soluções que possam talvez ajudar com o seu problema. Em ambos os casos você pode criar uma coluna ID em cada caso apresentado. Feito isso, vamos as soluções que pensei para tentar ajudar:

1) Criando essa coluna ID em ambos casos, verificar se ambos terão a mesma quantidade de linhas. Se elas tiverem a mesma quantidade, acredito que um INNER JOIN resolverá o problema;

2) Mas se não tiverem a mesma quantidade acredito que o FULL OUTER JOIN poderá resolver. Mas nesse caso, o FULL OUTER JOIN deverá seguir essa estrutura:

```
SELECT <seus dados>
FROM TableA  A
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB  B
ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE A.Key is NULL
OR B.Key is NULL
```

obs: Tendo em mente que a sua chave em ambas as tabelas serão os respectivos ID criados.

Espero conseguir ajudar.

Abraços